# Why frame of detailViewController always return me 1024*768

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app with split view controller.

I want to programmaticaly create and add subview to detailViewController in right bottom corner. To do that i try to get frame of detailView (app support autorotation, so that position not static)

i do next

in viewWillAppear for detailView i try to get frame and calculate position i need

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  [super viewWillAppear:animated];    

    CGRect btnRect = self.view.frame;
    //it always return 1024*748 width and height
    //even in landscape mode
    //when as i think must return 1024-321=703*748 pxls
    //where is my mistake? How i can get actual frame
    //dimensions for detailViewController in landscape orientation

    btnRect.origin.y = btnRect.size.height - 42;
    btnRect.origin.x = btnRect.size.width - 42;
    btnRect.size.height = 42;
    btnRect.size.width = 42;

    UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:someimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[btn layer] setFrame:btnRect];

   [self.view addSubview:btn];  
}
```

But it always show me that detailView frame has 1024*748 dimensions. When in landscape mode i think it must be 703*748. What i need to do to get actual detailView frame?

Comment: Have you set the right auto-resizing mask in code or interface builder?

Comment: No. What is best practice to do that?

Comment: view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; or in interface builder (in the dimensions tab for the view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should want to change the frame of the view in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method.

An example:
(This one will adjust scrollView2 to fit its new orientation (88 pixels lower then the mainview))

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        // Portrait
        self.scrollView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 88);
        [self drawContent];
    }
    else {

        // Landscape
        self.scrollView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);
        [self drawContent];
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: first of all i must create subview and place it on parent view, but i cant get right dimensions parent view to position subview how i need.

Comment: Thanx. I check orientation and create button depend of that.